# How does Android Jetpack's SavedStateViewModelFactory work?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

my viewmodel-savestate version is
`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha03'`

in version 1.0.0-alpha01 ,i can use

```
 MyViewModel myVM = new ViewModelProvider(this, new SavedStateVMFactory(this)).get(MyVM.class);
```

to create viewmodel with savestate,
but in version 1.0.0-alpha03 ,

```
SavedStateVMFactory
```

cant work , i need to use `new SavedStateViewModelFactory` but i dont konw what is the second params means,
the code may look like this below:

```
        myVM = new ViewModelProvider(this, new SavedStateViewModelFactory(getApplication(),xxxxxxx)).get(MyVM.class);
```

and i cant find any document about this in android developer website, sad

Comment: You don't need the gradle dependency `viewmodel-savedstate`.  **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx** does this already.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the [`SavedStateRegistryOwner` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/savedstate/SavedStateRegistryOwner.html), both `Fragment`, and `AppCompatActivity` implement `SavedStateRegistryOwner`, so you can just pass in `this`:

```
 myVM = new ViewModelProvider(this,
     new SavedStateViewModelFactory(getApplication(), this))
     .get(MyVM.class);
```

Just make sure you're using AppCompat `1.1.0`, which is when `AppCompatActivity` (and its base class, `FragmentActivity` and `ComponentActivity`) started to implement `SavedStateRegistryOwner`.

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, make sure to hit the check box next to the answer to accept it and remove the question from the queue of unanswered questions.

Comment: sorry to apologize, ask one more question, when i restart the phone , the save-state can't work , it's sth wrong in my code```  public SavedStateHandle handle;

    public MyVM(SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
        this.handle = savedStateHandle;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getNumbers() {

        if (!this.handle.contains(MainActivity.KEY_NUM)) {
            this.handle.set(MainActivity.KEY_NUM, 0);
        }
        return this.handle.getLiveData(MainActivity.KEY_NUM);
    }
```

Comment: Saved state doesn't persist across reboots - you'd need to [persist the data to disk](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) via SharedPreferences, a database, etc.

Comment: i got another problem in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926170/why-savedstatehandle-setjava-lang-string-java-lang-object-on-a-null-object-re] can u help me ,plz!!!!

Comment: @ianhanniballake This is convenient, but are there any disadvantages to using a different `SavedStateViewModelFactory` in each Fragment, as opposed to one per Activity (or per app, if that's possible)?

Comment: @big_m - no, there are no disadvantages. Doing it any other way will give you the wrong result (the saved state won't be added to the right `SavedStateRegistry` and hence, won't be removed when the Fragment is removed, etc, etc)