# Using SavedStateViewModelFactory in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, persistence, viewmodel, savedstateviewmodelfactory

I have a Timer that sends a notification when the timer is done. Clicking this notification restarts the activity, deleting all the timer information.
For this reason, I decided to use [saved State for View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate).

```
 class TimerViewModel(val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    val savedBundleTimerState : MutableLiveData<TimerState> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(
        TIMER_STATE, timerState.value) 
//rest of code
```

Then I'm getting a reference in the fragment:

```
class FragmentTimer : Fragment() {

lateinit var timerViewModel: TimerViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_timer,
        container,
        false
    )

    //reference to timerViewModel, using SavedState
    val application = requireActivity().application
    timerViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this,
        SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, this)).get(TimerViewModel::class.java)
```

But when I run the app I get the error

> 2022-02-05 15:04:01.945 8460-8460/com.example.pomodorotechnique
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.pomodorotechnique, PID: 8460
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception happened in constructor of class com.example.pomodorotechnique.TimerViewModel

I've searching how to define the SavedStateRegistryOwner and I run into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838759/how-does-android-jetpacks-savedstateviewmodelfactory-work), which is very illustrating, but still doesn't work when I run the app

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: It'll tell you why construction is failing further down the stacktrace, you just posted the first line. Referencing ``timerState.value`` is suspicious (is it valid? is it null?) but without seeing the full code it's just a guess. Also fyi you can just do ``val timerViewModel: TimerViewModel by activityViewModels()`` without needing to mess with factories and activity/application references

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely solved it!