# savedStateHandle not saving State

Tags: android, kotlin, persistence, viewmodel, viewmodel-savedstate

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71973157/using-savedstateviewmodelfactory-in-fragment) question I made some simple changes in my app, but it's no working as I expect.

I have a Timer that sends a notification when the timer is done. Clicking this notification restarts the activity, deleting all the timer information, which is stored mainly in the `viewModel`. For this reason, I decided to use saved State for `viewModel`.

Here's my `viewModel`:

```
class TimerViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

private val _secondsRemaining = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Long>(SECONDS_REMAINING)
val secondsRemaining : LiveData<Long>
    get() = _secondsRemaining
```

Here is how I use the `viewModel` in my `Fragment`:

```
private val timerViewModel by viewModels<TimerViewModel>()
```

When I start the timer, I save the value of the seconds remaining in the `LiveData`, on every Tick of the clock. When the timer finishes, the app sends the notification and the timer starts again, counting a new cycle:

```
timer = object : CountDownTimer(timerLengthSeconds * 1000, 1000){
        override fun onFinish(){
            (....)
        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            var secondsRemainingInCountdown = millisUntilFinished / 1000

            (...)

            _secondsRemaining.value = secondsRemainingInCountdown
         
        }
    }.start()
}
```

So, when the timer finishes, the app sends the notification but the timer has restarted, and the seconds remaining are getting updated (I've checked this via Logs).
When the user clicks the notification the `activity` gets killed and restarts, and the expactation would be to see the timer with the seconds remaining saved in the `LiveData`. But when the `activity` restarts, `LiveData` value is null.

I have also tried setting a value of 10, in case `LiveData` is null when first created

```
private val _secondsRemaining = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Long>(SECONDS_REMAINING, 10)
```

but when the activity restarts, I get 10 as the value of LiveData

I can't figure out the reason.

My second problem is that I want to save the state of a `LiveData` that stores a custom `class`, that saves the state of the clock

```
private val _timerState = MutableLiveData<TimerState>()
val timerState : LiveData<TimerState>
    get() = _timerState
```

Being this `class`:

```
    sealed class TimerState {

    object OnFocusRunning : TimerState()
    object OnRestRunning : TimerState()
    object OnFocusPaused : TimerState()
    object OnRestPaused : TimerState()
    object Completed : TimerState()
    object RestCompleted : TimerState()
    object NotStarted : TimerState()
}
```

But I haven't succeed in this, since `TimerState` is a custom `class` and not a primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a `SavedStateHandle` [you need to set your values on it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate#savedstatehandle) to store them. If you use `getLiveData` for a particular key, then that `LiveData` will update whenever you set a new value for that key. If you're setting it directly on the `LiveData`, you're bypassing the saved state:

```
class TimerViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    // create a LiveData that monitors this key in the saved state
    private val _secondsRemaining = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Long>(SECONDS_REMAINING)
    val secondsRemaining : LiveData<Long> get() = _secondsRemaining

    // expose a setter that updates the state - this will propagate to the LiveData
    fun setSecondsRemaining(remaining: Long) {
        savedStateHandle[SECONDS_REMAINING] = remaining
    }

}
```

As for your other problem, yeah you're limited in what you can store, and for custom classes you either need to [serialise them into a form you can store](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate#non-parcelable), or make them `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

In your case though, since that sealed class isn't doing anything special except being an instance of a type, I'd just make it an enum class instead - those are `Serializable` so you can throw the value straight in there!

```
enum class TimerState {
    OnFocusRunning, OnRestRunning // etc
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I've tried this code, but it's still not working. When the `activity` restarts, `LiveData` is still null. Probably you could have a look? 
https://github.com/arieldipietro/PomodoroTechnique

Comment: @ArielDiPietro where's the ``TimerViewModel``?

Comment: sorry I might have made a mistake when pushing the project. Should be working now

Comment: @ArielDiPietro if you mean the two `LiveData`s you're logging in the `init` block of `TimerViewModel`, those look ok to me and there's no reason they should be null (especially the one you're giving a default of `0`). But you know this state is lost when the app is intentionally closed, right? `SavedStateHandle`s are only there to keep your data when the system kills your app in the background, so you can restore that state (like `savedInstanceState` but for view models). If you're killing the activity yourself, you lose that state - if you want to persist it, use `SharedPreferences` or  a DB

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I guess I misundersood the whole concept from the beginning. I moved all the information easily to a DB and that solved everythin! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArielDiPietro I did the same thing when I first started using it, but yeah it's a temporary "app running state" kinda thing. Glad you got it working!

Comment: `SavedStateHandle` is almost completely pointless. It only works in one specific scenario - when system kills my app in the background. But there are other equally (if not more) common scenarios - for example when a user terminates app manually, or clears all apps stack, or restart the device. And in all of such scenarios, `SavedStateHandle` does not work! Imho it is better to just persist data you wanna keep on your own, just use `SharedPreferences`, `DataStore` or `Room`. And it is guaranteed to work in every scenario. I don't see a reason to bother with `SavedStateHandle`

Comment: @qkx it's the difference between user-initiated dismissal (i.e. the user explicitly closing the app) vs system-initiated dismissal where the system destroys the app process in the background, but it's still "open" as far as the user's concerned, and they expect to see the same state when they navigate back to it. To maintain the current session's state, you need to use things like `SavedStateHandle` and `onSaveInstanceState` to store info about that state, just in case the app process gets destroyed (and UI widgets handle this themselves)

Comment: User-initiated dismissal is meant to be treated as a "fresh start" without that old UI state, which is why the *saved state* mechanisms we're talking about (as well as widget state) are cleared when that dismissal happens. It means you don't need to worry about what's been happening to the app in your setup logic - if saved state exists, you use it during setup! If it doesn't, you just start fresh as normal. There are a few scenarios where you'd expect the state to persist - you can read about them here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#expectations

Comment: How do you make a class `Parcelable`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you need to implement the `Parcelable` interface, the docs tell you what methods you need to write (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) and there's lots of guides on the internet walking you through the process. You can try the `kotlin-parcelize` library (https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) which can automatically generate it, depending on the types of your class members. Anything non-standard and you'll still have to write a custom function to store/restore your state, but the library is a little nicer

Answer (score 6):

`SavedStateHandle` is not very useful. It only works in one specific scenario - when **system** kills my app in the background.

But what if **user** kills my app, or clears all apps stack, or restarts their device? *Those are equally if not more common scenarios*, and usually happen on a daily basis, and in all of such scenarios, `SavedStateHandle` won't help.

I think official docs doesn't do a good job explaining this, from the comments in this thread and all over stackoverflow it seems most people misunderstood `SavedStateHandle`. Me too. It should not be used to persist the app data, in fact it just (temporarily) persists session data.

Since most real-world apps usually must cover all aforementioned scenarios by for example persisting data in `SharedPreferences` or `DataStore` or `Room`, I really don't see many reasons to even bother with `SavedStateHandle` in most cases...Just skip it and use `SharedPreferences` and you'll save yourself time & keep your code simple.